# Microsoft Graph module : Some commands are missing on the module

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I just installed the Microsoft Graph module, namely `Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Governance`

It supposed to contain the cmdlet `Get-MgPrivilegedAccess`, but it's missing:

```
Get-Command -Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Governance
```

`Get-MgPrivilegedAccess` is not here.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get-MgPrivilegedAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.governance/get-mgprivilegedaccess?view=graph-powershell-beta) is available only for beta version.

By default, the SDK uses the Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0. You need to change the profile to beta by using the `Select-MgProfile` command.

```
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
```

Comment: Yes ! Thanks a lot !
It was so simple :):)